# Falha/Dúvida evento change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Olá,

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com um checkbox. Quando o checkbox fica true, dois campos devem ficar visíveis (por padrão estes campos são invisíveis), do contrário os campos ficam invisíveis. 
O checkbox funciona normalmente, porém se eu fechar o modal e abri-lo novamente, a função jquery deixa de funcionar, ou seja, quando altero os valores deste checkbox, os campos não ficam visíveis.

Segue meu HTML e funções jquery. Prints abaixo:

```
function visibleClass() {

   $("#div_responsavel, #div_grau").removeClass("row not-
   visible").addClass("row");

}
function invisibleClass() {

   $("#div_responsavel, #div_grau").removeClass("row").addClass("row not-
   visible");

}
```

//Função que é executada quando o checkbox é alterado

```
$("#cbx_responsavel").on("change", function () {

    if ($('#cbx_responsavel').is(':checked')) {
    visibleClass();
}
else {
    invisibleClass();
}
});
```

```html
//Este é o checkbox

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Possui Responsável *</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="cbx_responsavel">
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="cbx_responsavel">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//segue os dois campos, class not-visible (css com display none)
//html produzido com helpers do asp.net[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

<div class="row not-visible" id="div_responsavel">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        @Html.Label("txt_responsavel", "Nome Responsável", new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBox("txt_responsavel", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row not-visible" id="div_grau">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        @Html.Label("enum_parentesco", "Grau Parentesco", new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            @Html.DropDownList("DropDownGrauParentesco", null, "Selecione uma opção", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que ocorre é que quando o modal é fechado, os listener do checkbox são removidos. Uma forma de contornar isto é, escutar o evento do modal quando for aberto e somente depois instanciar a escuta do checkbox e suas ações.

Transforme sua escuta em uma função, no início do código chame ela cbx_responsavel(), depois, escute o evento de abertura do modal, quando aberto, chame ela novamente.

```
function cbx_responsavel(){

    // Remove o evento, garanti que não será duplicado
    $("#cbx_responsavel").unbind('change');

    $("#cbx_responsavel").on("change", function (){
        if ($('#cbx_responsavel').is(':checked'))
        {
            visibleClass();
        }
        else
        {
            invisibleClass();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como o Bruno disse, ao fechar a modal está removendo os eventos do elemento html gerado. Outra sugestão para resolução do mesmo seria:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(document).on("change", "#cbx_responsavel", function(){
         ... seu código
     });
});
```

Dessa forma, você está atrelando o evento ao elemento HTML do documento, que persistirá enquanto o documento estiver ativo.